# Curly line close together

Tags: symbols

I'm trying to find a symbol in LaTeX that looks like two curly vertical lines close together. Similar to,

```
\wr\wr
```

but closer together. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: what is the purpose of this?  (for example, does it decorate a "connector" in a commutative diagram?)  is the shape you want essentially the same as `\approx` rotated 90 degrees?  if that is the shape, then `\rotatebox` is probably the best approach.

Comment: It's to denote a seminorm - so a norm is `$\|.\|$` (the dot is just a placeholder for some variable - it's the two straight lines that either side that denotes the norm). Essentially it is the `\approx` sign rotated 90 degrees.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Many thanks - `\rotatebox` did the trick!

Answer (score 3):

Not that I like the symbol, but here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\dblwr{\wr\mkern-2mu\wr}
\newcommand{\seminorm}[1]{\mathopen{\dblwr}#1\mathclose{\dblwr}}

\begin{document}

$\seminorm{x}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How come you don't like the symbol?

Answer (score 1):

From the comment of barbara beeton,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\rotatebox{90}{$\approx$}

\end{document}
```

Gives the desired output.

Comment: I suggest you to use `$\|\cdot\|$` instead of `$\|.\|$`, as you commented.

Comment: when you use it, you should also apply `\mathopen` and `\mathclose` as noted by @egreg, to get the correct spacing.